# x86 Assembly 16-bit Relative Call

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode

I noticed that the following two assembly instructions are available in x86:

```
E8 cw    CALL rel16
E8 cd    CALL rel32
```

I'm confused how the instruction processor is able to differentiate between these two calls.  The only thing I can think of is if an application is 16-bit, the IP assumes the former, and if an application is 32-bit, the IP assumes the latter.  Is my interpretation correct, or is there a way to encode a `CALL rel16` into a 32-bit application?

Comment: The operand size (which determines whether it is rel16 or rel32) has a different default size depending on the mode of the processor (realmode/32-bit protected mode/16-bit protected mode/64-bit long mode/V8086 mode etc). You can see this [chart for details](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Operand-size_and_address-size_override_prefix). You can override the default with a 0x66 operand prefix. In 32-bit mode you can use 0x66 instruction prefix to change default from 32-bit operand size to 16-bit

Comment: @MichaelPetch So if I understand you correctly, I can use `0x66E8YYYY` (where 66E8 is big-endian, and YYYY is little-endian), which will be interpreted as a `CALL rel16` when contained within a 32-bit application.  Is that correct?

Comment: It would be 0x66 0xe8 0xYYYY where 0xYYYY is the little endian relative value

Comment: @MichaelPetch When I try this, my hardware is clearing the high-order half word of EIP after running the 16-bit relative version.  I am currently at address `0x56559053`, then run this command with `0x66E8EBFF`, and afterward EIP is set to `0x00009042`.  Clearly this isn't what I wanted, so I guess the answer is "no, you can't use this instruction in a 32-bit application to do anything meaningful".

Comment: You didn't ask about the side effects or how it worked. You asked about the encoding. The fact it cleared the upper part of EIP is documented and by design. From the Instruction set reference for 16-bit relative call it says this about EIP _tempEIP ← (EIP + DEST) AND 0000FFFFH; (* DEST is rel16 *)_ . You'll note that the upper bits are set to 0. You can read the ISA for `call` here: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html

Comment: You'd use this type of encoding in very very rare circumstances, I'd probably only expect to see this if you were writing an OS and you were using a combination of 32-bit and 16-bit code while transitioning into real mode (even then I'd use a different mechanism). I wouldn't expect someone to use this in a 32-bit usermode program (I can't think  of a reasonable use case for it)

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why is it you are interested in a rel16 encoding in 32-bit code?

Comment: I'm just trying to see how few bytes I can get an application down to.  It seems wasteful that the only way I can get the EIP value is to spend 5 bytes on a call instruction.  I was hoping that there was an equivalent like the JMP instructions that used a relative address constant less than 32-bits.

Comment: With the rel16 encoding you have to accept the nuances of how EIP is handled. Unless all your code was in the first 64KB of the segment such an encoding isn't very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was provided by *Michael Petch* in the comments of the question:

> The operand size (which determines whether it is rel16 or rel32) has a different default size depending on the mode of the processor (realmode/32-bit protected mode/16-bit protected mode/64-bit long mode/V8086 mode etc). You can see [this chart for details](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Operand-size_and_address-size_override_prefix). You can override the default with a 0x66 operand prefix. In 32-bit mode you can use 0x66 instruction prefix to change default from 32-bit operand size to 16-bit.

I noticed that the high order 16-bits of the EIP are zeroed out when using this instruction. Therefore, the `0x66 0xE8` 16-bit relative call has the following C++ semantics:

```
int16_t offset = ...;
EIP = (EIP + offset) & 0xFFFF;
```

So yes, it is possible to use the 16-bit relative call instruction within a 32-bit application.